# Set Custom DateFormat

Tags: ios, date, nsdateformatter, date-formatting

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz (zzzz)"];
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

Abow code given `Fri Feb 12 2016 14:11:16 GMT+5:30 (India Standard Time)` date format result but i have need `Fri Feb 12 2016 14:11:16 GMT 05:30 (India Standard Time)` date result format

Comment: replace the +/- with space.

Comment: And what about timezones that are `GMT - XXX`?

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include a new problem. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this .

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz (zzzz)"];
    [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSString *date=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
     //Replace "+" with Space""
    NSString *finalTimezone = [date stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+"
                                                                    withString:@" "];
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: What if it's `GMT-HH:MM`?

Comment: Not related to answer: please write "finalTimezone" instead of "FinalTimezone", variable names should always start with lowercase.

Comment: question is Edited. I gave correct answer According to question Related to timezone. Don't give negative marking. plz. Even you can also check question edited time and comment below question also.